# Visual Studio 2010 code display colour scheme - where do I find some properties?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, themes, color-scheme

I'm working on my own colour scheme for displaying code in visual studio. I can't find some text section name so I don't know where to change its colour. :( Can anybody help me and tell me where do  I find them, I mean what is the name of the following sections:

1. The grey one (documentation tag value and it's quote) - picture below

[image: XML Doc Comment Attribute]
<sub>(source: [yfrog.com](http://img684.yfrog.com/img684/5605/docatrvalue.png))</sub>

2. The olive colour: header of a asp.net in vb language document. - <% and underline.

`http://img12.yfrog.com/img12/7375/headerqt.png` (NOTE: image is now broken)

To write my code I use vb.net language.

Comment: @Glorfindel There's another broken image from the same source that should be fixed.

Comment: @gparyani sadly, that image is no longer available ...

Answer (score 2):

XML Doc comment, XML Doc Quote should be what your looking for. VB user types, User types and keyword also.

You might want to save yourself some time, i just did my color scheme, which i call Steam (based on Steam Platform from valve). It kind of looks like what your going for

I can't post a screenshot since i am new, but here is a download link. You can import it via the tools menu in VS. It includes resharper color settings.

[Steam for VS 2010/08](http://sevenupdate.com/files/steam.vssettings)

Comment: I found the answer for the first part of my question. It was VB Xml Atribute Value. :D But the second part is still without solution. :(

Answer (score 1):

The first one is `XML Doc Attribute`.

The second one is `HTML Element Name`.

Comment: Sorry but this is no answer for my question. Those are not properties I'm looking for. The first one is set to voilet and the second is set to orange. So it has to be something else. :( But anyway, thanks for help.